# How to typecast cMessage to message definition type

Tags: c++, omnet++

I have created a message type `WowMessage` by using OMNeT++'s message definition tool. Suppose that the class `Server`'s overriden `handleMessage` function always receives a `WowMessage` message, which is initially handled as a `cMessage`. How would I go about typecasting from `cMessage` to `WowMessage`so I can make used of the defined member fields and functions of the `WowMessage` type?

```cpp
void Server::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
{
    // Receives WowMessage which is subclassed from cMessage...
    // TODO: typecast from cMessage to WowMessage
    forwardMessage(msg);
}

void Server::forwardMessage(WowMessage *msg)
{
    send(msg, "port$o", msg->getDestAddress() - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dynamic_cast`, for example this way:

```
WowMessage * wowMsg = dynamic_cast<WowMessage *>(msg);
if (wowMsg) {
   // msg is an instance of WowMessage
} else {
   // another message
}
```